# Не обновляется переменная php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, php7

У меня есть небольшой код который отправляет переменную из js в php, и работает отлично, но переменная js у меня изменяется, но не изменяется php переменная, а надо чтобы изменились обе переменные, помогите пожалуйста.

```js
var user =  Number($('#number').html()) - 1;
```

```html
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['u_name'])) {
    $cl = $_GET['u_name'];
  } else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'document.location.href="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?u_name=" + user';
    echo '</script>';
    exit();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Мало информации. Покажите полностью код на JS, непонятно как отправляется переменная на сервер.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Answer (score 0):

В php вы принимаете значение `'u_name'`, которое, скорее всего, не является вашей переменной, полученной из js. Возможно это поле на вашей странице. Мало информации. Для более точного ответа покажите часть js где вы отправляете переменную на сервер.

Comment: Это весь js и весь php

Comment: @DmitriyMalishev, Тогда попробуйте менять переменную в тэге `script` внутри php. Также возможно, что скрипт с изменением переменной подключается позже скрипта php из-за чего изменения не передаются

Comment: Но мой js до php, то есть меняется он до отправки в php, а по поводу тега script в php, как мне это сделать, ведь если я его завернул он не будет работать, можете продемонстрировать пожалуйста?